# I recently update my python version, how do i add that version to my pycharm python interpreter?

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda3

I used

```
conda install python=3.9.4
```

on Anaconda Prompt to update my python version.
Then I tried opening a previous PyCharm project which ran on version 3.8.8. I want to use the updated version of python as my Python Interpreter. Does anyone know how to do that?

[image]

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CTRL + ALT + S` with that shortcut go to interpreter page and click select box.
There are show all end of the list. Click it and when the window pop up click '+' which is in the right side of window.
Then you should choose path of the new python. It's done!